# Regex with some special characters

Tags: android, regex

Could you please help me a regex with these conditions:

1. Only 3 allowed special characters: #, spaces, - (dash)
2. Numbers and alphabets allowed

Thanks,

Comment: it must have the above mentioned three special characters.

Comment: Try: `[a-zA-Z0-9\s\#\-]*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
^[-# \p{Alnum}]+$
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The character class `[-# \p{Alnum}]` matches hyphens, hashes, spaces and ASCII letters or digits
- The `+` means match one or more of those
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Answer (score 4):

Your regex would be,

```
[a-zA-Z0-9# -]+
```

In case of validation, add start and end patterns,

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9# -]+$
```

It allows one or more numbers or alphabets,  or `#` or `-` or spaces.

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the beginning of the line.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9# -]+` Allows  one or more numbers or alphabets,  or `#` or `-` or spaces.
- `$` End of the line.